# Binding Shape.Stroke to ResourceDictionary according an enum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I've created this ResourcesDictionary:

```
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="OffStroke" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF007226" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF003C15" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="OnStroke" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF6BBF8A" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF007A27" Offset="0.306"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

then i've created the following enum in codeBehind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerator 
/// </summary>
public enum Strokes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// off (value 0)
    /// </summary>        
    Off = 0x00,
    /// <summary>
    /// on (value 1)
    /// </summary>
    On = 0x01,
}
```

and I've put two ellipse inside the UserControl xaml side.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="ViewBoxRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="256" Height="256">
        <Ellipse x:Name="OnStroke" Stroke={StaticResource OnStroke}/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="OffStroke" Stroke="{StaticResource OffStroke}"/> 
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

and last I've insert the follow properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeXProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeX", typeof(Enums.Strokes), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(Enums.Strokes.Off));
    public Enums.Strokes StrokeX
    {
        get { return (Enums.Strokes)GetValue(myUserControl.StrokeXProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(myUserControl.StrokeXProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged("StrokeX");              
        }
    }
```

There's a possibility to binding the Ellipse Stroke property to stroke ResourceDictionary According to enum value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you define your gradient brushes in the resource dictionary like this:

```
xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Enums" ...

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static enums:Strokes.Off}" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="#FF007226" Offset="0"/>
  <GradientStop Color="#FF003C15" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static enums:Strokes.On}" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="#FF6BBF8A" Offset="0"/>
  <GradientStop Color="#FF007A27" Offset="0.306"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Now you can use these resource keys directly:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="OnStroke" Stroke="{StaticResource {x:Static enums:Strokes.On}}"/>
<Ellipse x:Name="OffStroke" Stroke="{StaticResource {x:Static enums:Strokes.On}}"/>
```

However, to bind to a dependency property is a bit more tricky. If you define your strokes the `App.xaml` resource dictionary, then you can create a `IValueConverter` along the lines of this:

```
public class ApplicationResourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Application.Current.Resources[value];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can bind to the property value using the converter, like this:

<sub>MyControl.xaml</sub>

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Converters">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:ApplicationResourceConverter x:Key="ApplicationResourceConverter"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
    <Ellipse Stroke="{Binding StrokeX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyControl}, Converter={StaticResource ApplicationResourceConverter}}"
             StrokeThickness="5"
             Fill="AliceBlue"
             Width="100"
             Height="100"
             Margin="0 0 0 20"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Click="OnButton_Click">On</Button>
      <Button Click="OffButton_Click">Off</Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

<sub>MyControl.xaml.cs</sub>

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeXProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeX", typeof(Enums.Strokes), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(Enums.Strokes.Off));

    public Enums.Strokes StrokeX
    {
        get { return (Enums.Strokes)GetValue(StrokeXProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(StrokeXProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void OnButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StrokeX = Enums.Strokes.On;
    }

    private void OffButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StrokeX = Enums.Strokes.Off;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could forgo any bindings and just use triggers to accomplish roughly the same thing. Here's an example style that shows how you might accomplish that:

<sub>Themes/Generic.xaml</sub>

```
xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Enums" ...

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static enums:Strokes.Off}" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="#FF007226" Offset="0"/>
  <GradientStop Color="#FF003C15" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static enums:Strokes.On}" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="#FF6BBF8A" Offset="0"/>
  <GradientStop Color="#FF007A27" Offset="0.306"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:MyControl}" TargetType="local:MyControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
        <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
          <Ellipse Name="_ellipse"
                   StrokeThickness="5"
                   Fill="AliceBlue"
                   Width="100"
                   Height="100"
                   Margin="0 0 0 20"/>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="OnButton_Click">On</Button>
            <Button Click="OffButton_Click">Off</Button>
          </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="StrokeX" Value="{x:Static enums:Strokes.On}">
            <Setter TargetName="_ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static enums:Strokes.On}}"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="StrokeX" Value="{x:Static enums:Strokes.Off}">
            <Setter TargetName="_ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static enums:Strokes.Off}}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: thanks, very much for your answer,
Just only a short modify in class converter
I put this obove the class

'[ValueConversion(typeof(Enums.Strokes), typeof(Brush))]'

and add cast to value returned:

'return (Brush)Application.Current.Resources[value];'

Comment: p.s.w.g.

this works only if use this code in a window.
But if I use this like a Usercontrol and then insert this control inside a window.
this code doesn't works

Comment: I didn't have any problem making it work inside of a user control. I've posted the full source for the user control in my updated answer. Also, I don't think the `ValueConversion` attribute is strictly necessary, and actually I think it's more useful to leave it as is so you could use it for different types of resources or keys.

Comment: Yes a totally agree with you , in your case is not typized like my converter.
But if I want use your control inside another assembly , I need to mergedictionary from external dll, isn't true?

Comment: @luka You don't need to dynamically register the `xaml` file for your resources. I think it's reasonable to expect any consuming applications to either add the appropriate styles at design time or provide their own themes. In any case, thinking about it a bit more, I'd say in this case, perhaps triggers would be more straight forward. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Okay , but if I use an external ResourceDictionary.xaml file , and in my control merge it .
How can I use that file without adding it dynamically ?
so,the solution is do not use an external file and put all in xaml design usercontrol code , this is true ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. Whenever I've had to do this, I set the build action of the xaml file with the default style sheet (usually something like `Themes/Generic.xaml`) to "Resources". Then any consuming application just needs to add `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>` to their `App.xaml`.

Comment: thanks p.s.w.g you are right , I set(written) my resources file link in to Themes/Generic,xaml and now works without add dinamically by code behind(runtime).
Tnahks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

this is how to use in a control that will be used in a window.

put this line in constructor of UserControl before InitializeComponent
suppose that your ResourcesDictionary file name is StrokeResources.xaml

```
 //merge the control resources used to current application 
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary(){Source = new Uri("/DLLNameSpace;component/ResourcesDictionaries/StrokeResources.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)});
```

then modify the xaml code :

```
<Ellipse Stroke="{Binding StrokeX, Converter={StaticResource ApplicationResourceConverter}}"/>
```

in this way the resources was add to actual application...